# Warning Message Before Running Macro (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a warning message when running a macro in Excel.

The warning message is to provide an option to 'cancel' prior to running the code below to clear cells.

When trying to add a message box to that below, where the user is encouraged to activate the macro from the ribbon, I cannot seem to get it to run without errors.

The sheet is locked, so only unlocked cells are to be cleared.

```
Sub Glazing_ClearContents(rib As IRibbonControl)
Dim rng As Range
Dim C As Variant
Set rng = Sheets("Glazing_Systems").Range("C12:I42")
    For Each C In rng
        If C.Locked = False Then
            C.ClearContents
        Else
        End If
Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: use inputbox and get answer from user. If they choose to continue, run your code, if not, exit sub.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   What code did you add for the message box?  If that is your problem, it would help to see it but please [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? And what specific "error" you get? It's hard to help you if you cannot show us what you're actually doing and how the code is actually failing.

Comment: I'd also caution against over-engineering your ribbon controls. A user has to deliberately press that button as it is. Few things are more annoying from a UX perspective than to be constantly asked "Are you sure you want to do this?"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The MsgBox now works well. Really appreciate you taking the time to feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found any trouble using the following code when asking if the user wants to use the macro

```
question = "Are you sure you want to run this Macro?"
If MsgBox(question, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
''''' Place your code to be executed if you clicked yes
else
'''''' Place your code to be executed if you clicked no
end if
```

Hopes this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit


Sub test()

    Dim Continue As String

    Continue = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to clear cells?", vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Attention")

    If Continue = vbYes Then
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```